# fav icon does not work in html5 Boilerplate

Tags: html, favicon, boilerplate

the fav icon in html5 Boilerplate doesn't work (doesn't show up)

I have tried it on localhost and also on a server but in both the cases it didn't worked.
Whats the to make it work .?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML5 Boilerplate doesn't use `link` elements for icons by default. Instead, it relies on the browser finding either favicon.ico or apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory.

If you put HTML5 Boilerplate in a sub-directory, whether in localhost or on a server, either no favicon will appear or an existing favicon in the server's root directory will appear. A quick fix for this is to add this line of code in the `<head>` section of index.html :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Even better would be to create a 16x16 PNG image (e.g. favicon.png) instead of using the 57x57 apple-touch-icon.png, which gets resized and therefore loses clarity.

See the **Favicons and Touch Icons** section of the [user guide](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.0.1/doc/html.md) for more details.