# Bookmarks page in safari icon is orange star?

Tags: favicon

I noticed that the bookmark icon on the favourites/bookmarks page in Safari is still incorrect.

I have:

Placed the favicon.ico file in the root directory
Gone to the file and done the whole ctrl F5 thing
Looked through this: https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet

But it's still an ugly orange star on black background and NOT my darling icon.

Any ideas are welcome and much appreciated...

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? How are you serving the website?

Comment: Hi Ry, thank you for the speedy response - the icon works in all other browsers, just not safari. Apparently it's called a 'boilerplate' logo - but I checked other threads and same steps to a resolution won't work (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116319/fav-icon-does-not-work-in-html5-boilerplate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Our serer is GoDaddy and we are using the Themify template.

Comment: If you look at your website’s source, is there a `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">` (where `icon.png` is anything that points somewhere other than your favicon)? If so, you’ll need to replace that file with your own apple-touch-icon (typically larger than a favicon) or delete the `<link rel="apple-touch-icon">` from the template.

Comment: Hi Ry - yes there is an area where you put any custom header code in for the website, wherein I placed the Link Rel tag with the icon image. Still no dice...

Comment: You would have to find and get rid of the existing one first.

Comment: Hi Ry, thanks for keeping-on with it. I don't think there's anywhere else to look because these pages are automatically generated in WordPress and there's really only one place to link stylesheets. I removed any trace of icons named apple-touch, but still chooses the wrong one. Ironically when I look at the logo file itself in a browser, and add it as a bookmark -  the favourite icon it uses is the right one!!

Answer (score 0):

So eventually after putting that header code in and rinsing all my directories of the apple-icon-touch file, the damn thing did disappear - it just took its time (about 5hrs+).